# azure function throws ServiceBusExceptions in ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I have basically an azure function with a service bus trigger and sometimes there occur Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException.

In the call stack isn't any custom code listed.
**Call Stack:**

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal>d__41.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<>c+<<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__40.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__42.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager+<ReceiveAndProcessMessagesAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
```

I check if something is documented here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#handle-service-bus-exceptions but I couldn't find something. The Service Bus has some Server Errors in the metrics, but these are not directly correlating with the exception in my logs.

**Azure function definition:**

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusFunction")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
        topicName: "%ServiceBusTopicName%",
        subscriptionName: "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%",
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
```

Has someone an idea what helps to avoid these exceptions?

**Edit**
Error Message

```
The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance. (MessageLockLost). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.
```

Comment: There isnt really enough info to understand whats going on here.  At least need the exception message.

Comment: Like @Wjdavis said, we need the exception message to be able to help you. Anyway, make sure you're using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus latest version.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Azure SDK's team, there's nothing to worry about that message, and you can get rid of it by increasing the LogLevel (host.json) for that particular library (from "Info" to "Warning"):

[image: Stop producing exceptions by increasing the LogLevel to Warning]
[Azure SDK for .NET forum - ServiceBusException Message Processing Error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28579)

**EDIT:**

Actually, to be precise, I had to add it inside 'applicationInsights':

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "logLevel": {
                "default": "Information",
                "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning" // HERE!
            }
        },
    }
}
```